# mysql_num_rows variable holding value as NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

`$row = mysql_num_rows($result);` has the value of `1` as expected. This is because the SQL query has found 1 row with the criteria. However, `$row[3]` is returning `NULL` when I was expecting a hash value. Any help will be appreciated. So my question is, why is `$row[3]` holding the value of `null` and not the hash value expected which is on my SQL database?

```
<?php 

    include('config.php');

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email';";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $password_relative = $row[3];

    echo "Row Value: ".$row."<br>";
    var_dump($password_relative); // holding null???
    var_dump($row); // holding 1 as intended

    echo "Inputed Password: ".$password."<br>";
    echo "Password Value On Server:".$password_relative."<br>";

    if ($row > 0) {
        // password_verify(password, hash);
        if(password_verify($password, $password_relative)) {
            // set seesion variables
            echo 'Successful sign in<a class="link" href="index.php">Go to dashboard</a>';
        } else {
            echo 'Password is wrong!<a class="link" href="SignIn.php">Go to sign in</a>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'The details given show that you do not have an account with us<a class="link" href="SignIn.php">Go to sign in</a>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: As you said "the sql query has found 1 row with the criteria", therefore $row[3] will not be set so it has NULL value. 

What I understand in your code, you may want something like this $row[1]->password (depend on what the name column)

Comment: @RRayasa $row[3] should hold the value of the 4 column

Comment: And yea, to see all errors you gotta turn on the error reporting by adding `error_reporting(-1)` at the very top

Comment: To hold values from columns you need to fetch them first, by `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` inside a `while` loop

Comment: @bad_boy mysql_fetch_assoc($result) will only return associative keys, not numeric ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_* functions are deprecated, so please don't use them anymore. Use PDO_mysql or MySQLi instead.

This being said, your $row var contains the number returned by mysql_num_rows(). It doesn't contain the row data.

To get the row data array with numeric keys only, you would need to use mysql_fetch_row().

More doc here : [php.net mysql_fetch_row() documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Answer (score 1):

1. you have defined `$row` as mysql_num_rows, which means that it is no longer a value, it is a count of the rows, and there is only one value;  there is no more `row[3]`

If you really want the value of that row, you would need to call it before the `mysql_num_rows`

2. You really should not be using `mysql_` functions;  they are deprecated (for very good reason;  they are highly vulnerable to sql injection, and will stop working very soon)  You should look up `mysqli_`.  Here's the information on [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) if you just want a count.

To get the value that you seek, you will need to do something like this

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
       echo $row[3];

}
```

There are some better ways of doing this, particularly using object-oriented style and using prepared statements (removing most risks of sql injection, faster queries, no need to escape variables etc.) See [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), however you can get what you want with the above.

Comment: That's good.  However, I'm not kidding about `mysql_` functions being deprecated, as is stated by the other answer as well.   I'd avoid using them at all to prevent developing bad habits :)